# Passar valor por POST com select option PHP

Tags: php

Quero passar o nome das opções por POST para outra página. Utilizei isto mas nao reconhece a variável.

```
echo "<form method=POST action=_search.php>";
echo "<select name=selectoption>";
    echo "<option value=nom>nome</option>";
    echo "<option value=prenom>ultimo</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type=submit name=btnsearch value=search >";
echo "</form>";
```

E na outra pagina para receber o valor,

```
$var = $_POST['selectoption'];
echo $var;
```

Comment: O noma da opção selecionada ou de todas as opções? Qual erro está mostrando? Fiz um teste com esse codigo seu e aqui fucionou sem erros.

Comment: Adicionei o nome em cada opção, e da me este erro Undefined index: selectoption

Comment: ja resolvi, era do nome das opçoes. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Pelo visto, seu problema é que você está confundindo **value** com a descrição da sua `<option>` pois eu testei estes dois códigos aqui e está resultando:

> prenom

e

> nom

No caso, você tem a opção 'nome' e 'ultimo' só que com valores de 'nom' e 'prenom' que são os valores retornados por `$_POST['selectoption'];`

Por isso se você quer receber 'nome' e 'ultimo' ao invés de 'nom' e 'prenom' você deve utilizar seguinte html no seu `<option>`:

```
echo "<select name=selectoption>";
echo "<option value=nome>nome</option>";
echo "<option value=ultimo>ultimo</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

ao submeter o formulário você terá como resultado:

> nome

ou

> ultimo

## Observação:

Eu utilizei dos seus códigos para realizar os testes, por isso todas as afirmações acima estão corretas.